# How to set credential to CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am calling backend api with access token to get credential likes accessKeyId, cognitoToken, secretKey and sessionToken.

How to set all these values to "CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider"?

Earlier I was using following code to for authentication.

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    activity, // Context
                    AppConstants.IDENTITY_POOL_ID, // Identity Pool ID
                    Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
            );

            //Set the google credentials
            credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);

            credentialsProvider.getIdentityId();
```

Above was working fine.

I dig android aws sdk, but didn't get any setter methods or constructor in which I can pass and set values.

Please help me. How can I set accessKeyId, cognitoToken, secretKey and sessionToken to CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.

Answer (score 0):

The credentials provider is meant to get you these credentials, there isn't a way to pass some arbitrary set in. It's meant to use Cognito's scoped down credentials, and allowing any arbitrary set would not follow that use case. If that's a hard blocker, you may be better off using an arbitrary AWS credentials provider.